# Is it possible to extend the TypeRolver to resolve custom types

Tags: reinforced-typings

Is there a way to resolve custom types or maybe create an generator that does?

My problem is that I'm trying to generate an interface for a SignalR hub.
The SignalR hub contains methods that returns a `Task<T>`.

As of now `Task<T>` is resolved as *any* which to me sounds like it did not match any of the resolvable types.

I'm looking for a way to resolve a `Task<T>` to a `Promise<T>`.

I know that I can use the `TsFunctionAttribute` to overwrite the return type like so:

```
[TsFunction(Type = "Promise<string>")]
public async Task<string> GetSomeValue() {...}
```

but that's not what I want.

I want a more global way of resolving a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

It was stupidly easy.

It can be achieved by setting up a substitute in the fluent configuration.

```
  public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
  {
        builder.Substitute(typeof(Task), new RtSimpleTypeName("Promise<void>"));
        builder.Substitute(typeof(Task<>), new RtSimpleTypeName("Promise"));
   }
```